# DOM selected all <tr>, how to traverse the <td>

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I have a table with trs that look like this.

```
<tr> 
  <td><a href="http://www.mysite.com">Link</a></td>
  <td>value 2</td>
  <td>value 3</td>
  <td>value 4</td>
  <td>value 5</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using xPath to select all `<tr>` and looping through them.

```
foreach($xpathResult as $item){
  //print the href of the first td
  //print the nodeValue of the second td
  //print the nodeValue of the 3rd td
  //print the nodeValue of the 4th td
  //print the nodeValue of the 5th td
}
```

How do I print the href of the first td and the `nodeValue` of each td thereafter? There's `firstChild` and `lastChild`, but how do I get to the middle s? I could use `firstChild->nextSibling` and `firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling` but isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop on `childNodes`, like so:

```
foreach( $trs as $tr) {
    echo $tr->firstChild->firstChild->attributes->getNamedItem( 'href')->value;
    foreach( $tr->childNodes as $k => $td) {
        if( $k == 0) continue; // Skip the first one
        echo $td->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: So isn't there something like `child(x)`?

Comment: Yes, you'd do `$tr->childNodes->item( x);`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just select the td's directly?

```
$results = $dom->xpath('//tr/td');
foreach($results as $td) {
   echo $td->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Because in reality I'm doing more than just printing them. So for each row, I format the first <td> a certain way, the second <td> a different way, etc. and then move to the next row and repeat. So I can't select the <td>s directly since they're not all treated the same.

Comment: nodelists can also be treated as an array, so `$results[0]` would give you the first td. or, doing it properly, `$results->item(0)`.

Comment: I think you're not paying attention to the fact that I have many rows and each has the <td>s. I don't need `->item(0), item(1)`, because I'm looping through it with a `foreach`. My question is about what happens inside the foreach.